# How to remove hiss from mp4 video?

Tags: audio, hiss

So I'm working on a project and apparently I'm deaf because I've spent hours editing video and listening to myself talk.

The problem I'm having is that there's a hiss in words like 'class' and every answer I've gotten is that I need to redo it with a new microphone and make sure it's far away from my face but I've literally turned four hours of video into like one hour of video over the course of probably a good month and I'd like to not do that so I was hoping there was a way to fix it digitally.

Because I know it's there, I asked a friend and he was like, I couldn't listen to this for long because of the hiss. So I feel like I must be deaf at the frequency or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recording quality is definitely not as bad as your thinking. There is just too much sibilance (hissing sound during 's' or 'sh') hence the harshness. The best possible way would be to go for a De-Esser,in which you can control this sibilance and not completely remove it. It comes in the form of a plug in depending on which software your using. I think you'll find it in any open source DAW like Audacity. Go for a video tutorial on YouTube to learn how to operate the De-Esser. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not awesome audio quality, but not terrible either. Easy thing to try would be EQ.

Use a narrow band (small Q factor or notch), and try pulling out around 4KHz. That likely won't be exactly right, but the sibilance usually lives around there... 2-4KHz.

Experiment with the width of the notch and the amount that you're pulling out.

To be sure, it sounds like the recording is heavy on the higher frequencies, so you'll want to have as tight a notch as possible to avoid making the whole thing sound dull. But I think a modest adjustment will suffice, as I don't think it's as bad as you're thinking.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by pulling out?

Comment: Also, my friend literally called it 'harsh' and the place I'm submitting the video complained about it. Does it sound harsh to you?

Comment: By pulling out, I mean 'lowering the volume'. The way an EQ works is by picking a frequency and then adjusting the volume of that particular frequency. Now, you can't actually just pick _one_ frequency, you're always affecting frequencies on either side of the one you chose. So that's why I suggest either a 'notch' or a 'small Q factor'. Both of those things work to affect a smaller, more targeted set of frequencies.

Comment: And yes, it's a bit harsh. You're kind of missing _all_ of the lower frequencies. This makes it sound a bit like you're using a telephone as your microphone.

Comment: Could this be due to my editing software or is it more likely my microphone?

Comment: Unlikely the software itself (although you could have settings in there to affect the sound of course). What microphone did you use to record?

Comment: A Logitech USB H390